# Adding External logins with Facebook and Google to ASP WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, google-authentication

+someone please guide me on a way to add Adding External logins with Facebook and Google to this very informative post, http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/ , with information on this post, http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/ . i tried implementing this but i get errors in the AccountController, FacebookAuthProvider, and GoogleAuthProvider, i have uploaded my all implementations to Github...here (*cant post a third link due to reputation restrictions*) **`github.com/McKabue/Examination-Pastpaper-Archive`**

Comment: What version of webapi you are using?

Comment: latest version, v5.2.3